# How to define an api adress for an asp net core application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.Net Core application and I would like to use a REST API that I have created. Do you know a proper way to pass the adress of my API to my controllers ? I can create an Interface with my connection string for my controllers but I would like to know there is a way to use the startup file for example.

Comment: What part of the URL are you looking to configure?
This part: www.test.com **/api/Customers**
or
this part: **www.test.com** /api/Customers

Comment: This part: /api/Customers

Comment: I would like to know if we can pass it to all the controllers using startup.cs. I already know how to connect my asp net application to my api

Comment: Use attribute routing, it's an easy way to go about it: https://codeopinion.com/asp-net-core-mvc-attribute-routing/

Comment: Are you calling an API from an API?  If you post a code example it might help clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks J.N. but that's not really what I was looking for (or maybe I don't understand you answer). What I would like to do is to pass a connection string to all my controllers in my application.

For example I have 5 controllers which will connect to my API and call differents controllers in this API. At the moment, the adress of my API is something like localhost:56000 but when I will put this on a server, I will have to modify all the adresses in every controllers. Do you think that I can pass a string in the constructor of every controller ? But if there isn't a better solution, I will create an Interface I think.

Comment: Ahh, you're **connecting to** an API, which is not the same as your ASP.net Core application? (You can create API's with ASP.net core too, thought you were talking about that). But yes, the best thing is to create an interface, and an implementation of that interface, for your API in your application, and then use dependency injection to pass it to the controllers. It also makes It possible to unit test your controllers by mocking the API. Another option is to call the API using Javascript in the views of the application, have you considered that

Comment: Sorry, I'm french so maybe I didn't use the good words ! Thank you J.N. I will use dependency injection because I don't want to use javascript in my view